# How would I use a wildcard in a css selector?

Tags: css

`link[type*="application/*+xml"]`

I'm trying to match either `rss+xml` or `atom+xml` so I want to use a wildcard in that spot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `$` wildcard, which selects element whose attribute value ends with a specified value.

```css
div{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;  
}

link[type$="rss+xml"] + div{
  background: green;
}

link[type$="atom+xml"] + div{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link type="application/rss+xml" />
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard selector is used to select multiple elements simultaneously.

```
[attribute*="value"] { 
    // CSS property 
}
```

It will look like this

```
[class*="str"] {
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
```

For Example:-
You can do like this.

```
<div class="first_str">The first div element.</div>
<div class="second">The second div element.</div>
<div class="my-strt">The third div element.</div>
<p class="mystr">Paragraph Text</p>
```

Now it will select all classes, named with ***`str`*** like:-
**first_str, my-strt, mystr**